# App crashes at new FTPClient();

Tags: android, eclipse, apache, import, ftp

So I am using an app to edit a text file on an FTP server. I have imported the apache commons .jar with the sources attached. The code, in Eclipse, reads no errors.

I've narrowed it down to the line of code that's malfunctioning.

```
View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String g = et.getText().toString();
        et.setText("");
        FTPClient con;
        try{
            /*con = new FTPClient();
            con.connect("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx");

            if (con.login("xxxxx", "xxxxx"))
            {
                con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                String data = "/public_html/prompt/status.txt";

                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
                boolean result = con.storeFile("/status.txt", in);
                in.close();
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();
            }*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
};
```

In this code snippet, the last bit of code that's not commented out is:

```
FTPClient con;
```

When I run this, it works perfectly.

However, when I uncomment:

```
con = new FTPClient();
```

even though it's within the "try-catch" the app crashes.

I do believe I imported the .jar correctly. Is there anything else I might be doing wrong?

LogCat says the following:

```
Could not find class "org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient"
```

So i'm gussing this means I didn't import it right?

Comment: Okay I checked the logcat and it is saying:
"could not find class for apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient"
So I'm guessing this means I did not import it right?

Comment: This means the jar is not in your classpath. THis is a Error rather than an Exception and will jump out of your try catch because it doesn't match but is still throwable.

Comment: Did you copy this ``apache commons .jar`` to ``libs`` folder under your project root?

Comment: No I did not, I will do that now

Comment: THANK YOU harism that solved my problem. I just needed to add that to my libs folder.

Comment: Just as an FYI, you can do a try { } catch (Throwable t) { } whenever this sort of thing happens, and that will catch anything that gets thrown.  (I think @Greg was eluding to that.)